# How do I convert a hexadecimal number into binary in Redshift?

Tags: python, sql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to convert hexadecimal numbers into binary. I haven't been able to find a redshift function that would work.

I have tried the two following functions:

select strtol('4D',2) & select to_binary('4D')

(to_binary function doesn't exist but to_hex does)

I have also tried finding a python UDF but have had no luck.

Example:
If I converted the hexadecimal 4D into binary I would expect 01001101

Comment: Cannot you use standard python? Why Redshift only?

Comment: *" I haven't been able to find a redshift function that would work. "* Most likely you will have to [CREATE](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_FUNCTION.html) one yourself..  `CREATE FUNCTION` you can also connected it with @qqqqq answer.. -> *"Creates a new scalar user-defined function (UDF) using either a SQL SELECT clause or a Python program. "*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a UDF to do the same

```
create function hex_to_bin(h varchar)
returns varchar immutable as $$
    return bin(int(h,16))[2:]
$$ language plpythonu;

select hex_to_bin('4D');

hex_to_bin
1001101
```

Update:
A new version with leading zeros. Need a second parameter to specify the length of the output

```
create or replace function hex_to_bin(h varchar, number_of_bits int)
returns varchar immutable as $$
    return bin(int(h,32))[2:].zfill(number_of_bits)
$$ language plpythonu;

select hex_to_bin('4D',10);

hex_to_bin
0010001101
```

Comment: Thank you! This is is what I was looking for! Do you know if there is a way to include the leading zeros?

Comment: Updated the answer with a version of the function includes leading zeros

Comment: You are the best!

Answer (score 0):

> `dec = int('4D', 16); print("in Binary =",bin(dec))`